# how to pass variable in using post method with jquery .load()

Tags: jquery

I want to pass the variables `name`, `email` into the `.load()` event.

```
var email = $('#reg-email').val();
var name = $('#reg-name').val();
$("#user-detail").load("proc/reg-step2.php",{ "name": "name" , "email": "email" }, function() {
    $("#ajaxLoader2").remove();
});
```

What should be the syntax for this section so that the variable is passed instead of jst the strings I've written here `{ "name": "name" , "email": "email" }`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a variable instead of a literal:  `{ "name": name, "email": email }`

Comment: is my .load() syntax above incorrect (after changing to what you've told here)?? It is not working. I want to pass the variables and still use the callback function too.

Comment: If I write is the way you've mentioned here, the file `reg-step2.php` is not loaded at all.

Comment: You're passing a string literal.  You need to pass a variable. (eg, `{ propName: someVariable }`

Comment: If i use the the above exact code I've written in my Question, the strings are passed properly. If I change the section `{ "name": name, "email": email }`, than the XHR result doesn't even show that the file reg-step2.php is loaded at all (am using chrome developer tool)

Answer (score 1):

In an object literal you can use quotation marks around the property names, but you shouldn't use them around the variable names that you use in the values:

```
{ "name": name, "email": email }
```

You can also write the object literal without quotation marks around the property names:

```
{ name: name, email: email }
```

You can also mix quoted and unquoted property names, as you need:

```
{ "name": name, email: email }
```

If you would have a property name with special characters, like `name+email`, you need quotes around it in the object literal:

```
{ "name+email": name + ', ' + email }
```